# How To: A Laravel Auth User Provider that finds users indirectly

Tags: laravel, authentication

My Laravel project involves businesses and their employees.  The main Eloquent models are Businesses, Users and Roles.  A User can have multiple Roles, each with a different Business.

When it comes to authentication, the Laravel Auth setup is a good fit, with one exception: A User does not have an email address.  Instead, each of their Roles has an email address, and the user can log in using any one of these.

My user object has the `password` and `remember_token` fields.  It seems to me that this object should still implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface, and that it should do so by importing the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait.  Does this sound right?

When it comes to the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface:

- I think that I can extend the Eloquent provider implementation, `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`, and override only the `retrieveByCredentials()` method, but I am not sure.  Will I need to override other methods as well?
- If I do extend the Eloquent provider implementation, how do I go about injecting the `$hasher` and `$model` arguments when I register the new user provider in the `boot()` method of my `AuthServiceProvider`.  Where do these values come from (see below)?

> ```
> public function boot()
> {
>     $this->registerPolicies(); 
>     Auth::provider('role', function ($app) {
>         $hasher = ''; // ????
>         $model = ''; // ???
>         return new UserViaRoleProvider($hasher, $model);
>     });
> }
> ```

Comment: It depends. If your roles are set in stone you could make a database table for each role instead of a global roles table. That way Each Role-table contains all the info for that role, User table is only responsible for the global info that each role has in common, so email for example. That way you can still use the Auth system. But just make relationships Between User and the role.

Comment: Hi Christophvh, I think we are using the word 'roles' in different ways.  A role is simply an employee role, so 'plumber', 'carpenter', 'shop assistant', etc.  So if I have 10,000 users, there will be at least 10,000 roles.  (A user must have a least one role active at all times).

Comment: Do all 10 000 roles have differtent functionality on the website? Because to me they all seem like Employees. But have different Permissions. Giving employees different rights, can you solve with policies and permissions. But maybe i don't understand your use-case yeah. Because you can Create Admin-accounts this is the email from a user that can log in. That user can have the rights to manage several roles for example

Comment: Christophvh, the roles have nothing to do with permissions on the site.  I probably should have called them EmploymentContracts or StaffMembers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found that it was easier to create my own implementation of the UserProvider interface.  The only method which required a bit of thought was `retrieveByCredentials()`.  It searches for the Role, then returns the related user.

Although I was successful in logging in, I ultimately abandoned the approach because there are other parts of the Auth system that assume there is a 1-to-1 relationship between user and email.  For example, the Password Reset functionality.